# How to conditionally run parameterized tests in JUnit5?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

Exactly I mean tag **@EnabledIfSystemProperty** using with **@ParameterizedTest** tag.
When I use **@EnabledIfSystemProperty** with **@Test**, the test method is being disabled and after tests run it is grayed out on the list (as I expect):

```
@Test
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "env", matches = "test")
public void test() {
    System.out.println("Only for TEST env");
}
```

Whereas I use **@EnabledIfSystemProperty** with **@ParameterizedTest**, the test is green on the list after tests run but it is not actually executed:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "env", matches = "test")
@ValueSource(strings = {"testData.json", "testData2.json"})
public void test(String s) {
    System.out.println("Only for TEST env");
}
```

I execute tests from IntelliJ IDEA.
I need the test to be grayed out on the list. Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Jupiter, ie 5.7.2 ?

Comment: @johanneslink no, my version is 5.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the parameterized test to a `@Nested` test and apply the condition to it:

```java
@Nested
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "env", matches = "test")
class Inner {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"testData.json", "testData2.json"})
    public void test(String s) {
        System.out.println("Only for TEST env: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it could be some solution